# How can I send Image data through JSON from an Image Tag that has blob URL in src?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, angularjs, json

I am working on a project that uses Angularjs for the FrontEnd and Java Webservices in the backend. I am trying to upload and send an Image through JSON.

The Images when uploaded, generates a blob url **( blob:http://localhost/a34ac19f-3320-4cdf-b30f-e1b0a0e7a745 )** in src. How can I read it and convert it to Base64 or other types that can be sent through JSON?

Answer (score 0):

First of all add this custom directory right below your controller :

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then in you view use it like this :

```
 <input type = "file" name="files" file-model = "myFile"/>
```

In your controller function when youf form will submitted :

Do it like this :

```
$scope.formSubmit = function(){
         var file = $scope.myFile;
         var fd = new FormData();
         fd.append('profilepic', file);
         fd.append('action', 'add');

         $http.post('yourjavafile', fd, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
                }).success(function (response) {

                        if (response) {

                        } else {

                        }
                    });;
}
```

Comment: The image upload process is handled by a seperate jQuery Library which I am supposed to use here. Is there any other solution than this? Anyway thanks for this solution.

Comment: Yes this is pure angular file upload example.